# Create POJO from XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I am trying to convert a `Pojo to XML` using the `JAXB` library.

I need the end result to look something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>

 <!--other stuff-->

</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried a few different ways but so far I have no success, here is my latest attempt.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "soap:Envelope")
public class Envelope {

  private SoapBody soapBody;

  public String toString() {
      return "ClassPojo [SoapBody = " + soapBody + "]";
  }

  public SoapBody getSoapBody() {
      return soapBody;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "soap:Body")
  public void setSoapBody(SoapBody soapBody) {
      this.soapBody = soapBody;
  }
}
```

this converts to the following result (but it's missing the `XMLNS` lines):

```
<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>
<!--Other stuff-->
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried adding a namespace tag to the declaration:

`@XmlRootElement(name = "soap:Envelope", namespace = "soap")`

but it just made the line convert to this `<ns2:soap:Envelope xmlns:ns2="soap">`

Edit:

```
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = 
        JAXBContext.newInstance(MyOtherStuffObject.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(myObject, os);
    os.flush();
```

Comment: Does the soap namespace have to be explicit ? <Envelope xmlns="namespace"> should be equivalent to <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="namespace"> for most parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried adding a namespace tag to the declaration:
>
> @XmlRootElement(name = "soap:Envelope", namespace = "soap")
>
> but it just made the line convert to this

you are in one step out of what you need...

soap namespace is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` not `soap` so... what if it will be like that?

`@XmlRootElement(name = "soap:Envelope", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")`

BTW. but do you really need to create SOAP Envelope manually? actually standard package `javax.xml.soap` has everything to work with SOAP where you can wrap your "other stuff" into SOAP Envelope and do not care about building it by your-self?

**UPDATED:** 
I strongly recommend to use normal frameworks when working with SOAP web services, like Apache CXF or such, instead of manipulating SOAP on that low level.

But it can be done with standard JDK classes. 
Example code:

```
package com.foo.tests;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConstants;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class TestSOAPMessage {

    static MessageFactory factory;
    static DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory;
    static JAXBContext jaxbCtx;
    static com.foo.tests.pojo.ObjectFactory myStuffFactory = new com.foo.tests.pojo.ObjectFactory();
    static {
        try {
            factory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
            documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.foo.tests.pojo.MyStuffPojo.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            // prepare test MyStuff JAXB POJO
            com.foo.tests.pojo.MyStuffPojo myStuff = myStuffFactory.createMyStuffPojo();
            // populate myStuff Pojo
            myStuff.setMyPropertyA("property A");
            myStuff.setTimestamp(Calendar.getInstance());
            myStuff.setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            //---
            // marshal JAXB Pojo to DOM Document
            Document myStuffDoc = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

            //*** myStuff has @XmlRootElement annotation
             jaxbCtx.createMarshaller().marshal(myStuff, myStuffDoc);

            //*** myStuff does not have @XmlRootElement annotation wrap it and use JAXBElement instead
//          JAXBElement<com.foo.tests.pojo.MyStuffPojo myStuff> jaxbWrapper = myStuffFactory.createMyStuffPojo(myStuff);
//          jaxbCtx.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbWrapper, myStuffDoc);

            //marshal JAXB Pojo to DOM Document 
            Document myStuffDoc = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            jaxbCtx.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbWrapper, myStuffDoc);
            //Create SOAPMessage
            SOAPMessage myMessage = factory.createMessage();
            //Optional if we'd like to set those properties...
            myMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");
            myMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "utf-8");
            // set myStuff into SOAPBody
            myMessage.getSOAPBody().addDocument(myStuffDoc);        
            //All done. Save changes
            myMessage.saveChanges();

            // Just for test: print message
            ByteArrayOutputStream finalBos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            myMessage.writeTo(finalBos);
            System.out.println("my Message: \r\n" + new String(finalBos.toByteArray()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your idea about not creating the SOAP envelope manually, I have added the question with the marshalling code, how would I go about changing it to adding the envelope to it?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the `namespace` attribute in your java bean? or

JAXB also provides the @XMLSchema annotation, which we can use to generate namespace.

You can do as below.

```
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" , elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={     @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", prefix="xsi"),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", prefix="soap")
    }
)
```

Have also a look on [this](http://www.cubearticle.com/articles/core-java/jaxb/generate-namespace-schema-with-jaxb)